# Fetch post from react client becomes undefined in NodeJS express backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs

I'm new to NodeJS and react.
I'm trying to make a form to register a new user that will be saved to a json.file(Not using a DB for this project). 
I've been trying all day to find out why my fetch post request ends up empty on backend.
I've tried posting with postman which works, I've checked the network on console and it states that there were no error with the fetch request.
my react frontend

```
class Register extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      subbed: true,
    };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange= (e)=> {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})

  }
  handleSubmit= e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.state)

    const { username, password, subbed } = this.state;
    var data = {username: this.username, password:this.password, subbed:this.subbed}
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/reg', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode:'no-cors',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
      }

    })
    console.log(username)
    console.log(password)
    console.log(subbed)

  }

  render() {
    const { email, password, subbed } = this.state;
    return (
      <header className="App-header">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} method="POST">
          <label>E-post:</label>
          <br />
          <input
            name="username"
            type="text"
            value={email}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
          <br />
          <label>Lösenord</label>
          <br />
          <input
            name="password"
            type="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
          <br />
          <label>Vill du ta del av vårt nyhetsbrev?</label>
          <input
            name="subbed"
            type="checkbox"
            checked={subbed}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
          <br />
          <input type="submit"></input>
        </form>
      </header>
    );
  }
}

render(<Register />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

And my NodeJS for the post:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyparser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const port = 3001
const fs =require('fs')
const path= require('path')
app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyparser.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }));
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded());

app.post('/reg', (req,res)=>{



    console.log(req.body.user)
    console.log(req.body.username)
    console.log(req.body.password)
    console.log(req.body.subbed)
    res.send(req.body.username+ ' '+req.body.password +' '+req.body.subbed)
fs.readFile('users.json', (err, data)=>{
    if (err) throw err
    const users = JSON.parse(data);

})
let user ={
    username :req.body.username,
    password : req.body.password,
    subbed:req.body.subbed
};
var arr = [];
arr.push(user);
fs.writeFile('users.json', JSON.stringify(user), err=> {
    if (err) throw err

    res.send('Done!')
})
})
```

Any idea where i went wrong or any who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: you used the wrong values when setting your data,eg `username: this.username` should  be `username:username` since you destructured the values from `this.state`

Comment: Yeah, you can change:

`var data = {username: this.username, password:this.password, subbed:this.subbed}`

To:

`const data = { username, password, subbed };`

Comment: @PatrickEvans thanks i tried it and the same problem persists :/

Comment: What are your console logs outputting? Specifically, the logs within your `handleSubmit` function?

Comment: @KierenHughes it's outputting the data i typed into the form(i.e. {username: "asd", password: "asd", subbed: true}) but on the serverside it becomes undefined as if nothing was sent or as it wasn't wasn't recieved properly

Comment: I think it could be related to the 'no-cors' value. I think if you specify 'no-cors' you are limited to a subset of 'Content-Type' values:  application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain. Maybe try 'cors' as oppose to 'no-cors'.

Comment: You'll need to enable cors on your node server as well.

Comment: @KierenHughes changed to cors and also tried removing it and it resulted in cors policy error instead and suggesting no-cors for requests
EDIT: saw you latest reply after posting my comment will try it out!

Comment: Awesome! No problem :)